# Steganography Digital Watermark Method

Tags: watermark, steganography

Is there any method for hide text in Images besides using LSB Method for steganography - digital watermark? I wanted to make a research for hiding a text in image. But I don't want to use LSB method.

Comment: Yes. Good luck with your research.

Comment: @Reti43 Did you know any other method besides LSB?

Comment: This may be useful: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/45a1/f9a9cf2d4ead6a8675c506202d33255534cc.pdf